# selecting cousins - i.e. issues with both preceding and preceding-sibling

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

If I have the following xml

```
<root>
  <house id="1">
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
  </house>
  <house id="2">
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
  </house>
</root>
```

I want to count (counting is NOT the issue, the construction of the xpath is the problem, I'll append an example at the end that is more accurate but uglier to explain) the preceding 'cousins' as
I process the xslt

and the following xslt (1.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <counts>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/house/occupant"/>
      </counts>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="occupant">
      <previous>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::occupant)"/>
      </previous>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get what I want

```
<counts>
  <previous>0</previous>
  <previous>1</previous>
  <previous>2</previous>
  <previous>3</previous>
</counts>
```

but this doesnt work if occupants can appear elsewhere in the xml tree e.g.

```
<root>
  <house id="1">
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
    <next_door>
      <house id="2">
        <occupant>
        </occupant>
        <occupant>
        </occupant>
      </house>
    </next_door>
  </house>
  <house id="2">
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
    <occupant>
    </occupant>
  </house>
</root>
```

I'm not interested in 'next_door', in fact I'm ONLY interested in 'cousins' (and siblings) in the tree, i.e. things on the path 'root/house/occupant'

the above will count any occupant, and preceding sibling will only count, quite sensibly, siblings.

I feel that I want to count

/root/house/occupant[some predicate that says this node precedes the current one]

---

P.S. The actual issue is more like this, i.e. extracting data from specific cousins (but explaining the output is quite convoluted, where counts are nice and easy to explain)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <counts>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/house/occupant"/>
      </counts>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="occupant">
      <previous_and_next>
        <previous>
          <xsl:copy-of select="(preceding::occupant)[1]"/>
        </previous>
        <next>
          <xsl:copy-of select="(following::occupant)[1]"/>
        </next>
      </previous_and_next>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've had this issue before, but I think solved it, sadly I didnt post it here, so I cant find the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `xsl:number` e.g.

```
  <previous>
    <xsl:number count="root/house/occupant" level="any"/>
  </previous>
```

As you want to substract one e.g.

```
  <previous>
    <xsl:variable name="count"><xsl:number count="root/house/occupant" level="any"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$count - 1"/>
  </previous>
```

To select with set "except" operations based on node-count in XPath 1.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="occupant">
  <previous>
    <xsl:variable name="self-and-following" select=". | following::occupant"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cousins" select="/root/house/occupant[count(. | $self-and-following) = count($self-and-following) + 1]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($cousins)"/>
  </previous>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: as I said in the original, the counting is not the issue, let me update the post to make it more explciit

Comment: I've updated it, hopefully its a bit more clear, the final example works, until there are repeated elements in the xml tree at the wrong 'level'.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: ew....complicated isnt it to do something you'd think should be simple...so the predicate basically says, only include nodes where the current one isnt in self-and-following?

Comment: isnt following-sibling a subset of following? i.e. you don't need following-sibling?

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, that's true, will fix the sample.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, XPath 2 has an operator `<<` (`<xsl:variable name="cousins" select="/root/house/occupant[. &lt;&lt; current()]"/>`) and has an `except` (`<xsl:variable name="cousins" select="/root/house/occupant except (., following::occupant)"/>`) operator.

Comment: works for me.....I'll leave it open for another hour or so to see if we've not missed something blindingly obvious...this doesnt ring a bell...but maybe my previous problem with axes was something completely different

Comment: ah interesting about XPath2? so this is easy in xpath 2?

Comment: it unfortunate that in order to get the siblings you need to know the absolute path...but I'll live with that

Comment: Well, your attempt to express it was `/root/house/occupant[some predicate that says this node precedes the current one]`, so it has the absolute path as well.

Comment: oh yes I completely agree....its just unfortunate u can't express is as an axis, relative to your current context

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you want. From the context of `occupant` on the path of `/root/house/occupant` you can select the preceding occupants on the same path using:

```
preceding-sibling::occupant | ../preceding-sibling::house/occupant"
```

Comment: yes you can, in general though if there's a deep tree, you would end up with a very long expression thats not very nice to maintain if the tree structure changes

Comment: In general, if there's a deep tree, you can use the `ancestor` and `descendant` axes to cut to the level you want - for example: `preceding-sibling::occupant | ancestor::house/preceding-sibling::house/descendant::occupant`. But then you also might get descendants that are not on the same exact path.